digamma and trigamma values
I have a question regarding the calculation of the digamma and trigamma functions. For the argument k = 3.39363019528072, in Maple I get:
Psi(k) = 1.067389936
Psi(1, k) = 0.3422792587

In Matlab I get:
psi(k) = 1.06738993602083
psi(1,k) = 0.342279258672357

But in R I get:
digamma(k) = 1.06738993592474
trigamma(k) = 0.0868302335791374

To approximate the trigamma function, I wrote an R script that uses the asymptotic development and recurrence relation presented in the Wikipedia page. I get the same result (0.0868302335791374) as the one given by the native R function. Why the difference between the R results and those in Matlab and Maple? Which of the results is correct?

I cannot reproduce this error. trigamma(k) |> print(digits = 16L) gives me [1] 0.3422792586723569.

And digamma(k) |> print(digits = 16L) too is different from the posted output. Mine is [1] 1.067389936020827.

You may have another trigamma() function masking the base one.  Try getAnywhere("trigamma").  It should show just one object in the base package.  Or maybe your script left a copy somewhere.

R does have the psigamma function. Check whether your psigamma(k, 1) matches your trigamma(k). Though you would be safer to use the namespace resolution operator :: ie base::trigamma(k)

Also, from Wikipedia: cc <- c(1,1/2,1/6,-1/30,1/42,-1/30,5/66,-691/2730,7/6); pp <- c(-1, -2,-3,-5,-7,-9,-11,-13,-15); sum(cc*k^pp) gives 0.3422793  (haven't tried printing more digits)
